# solr boost query/function based on search query

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud

I have some search keyowrd called shoe , for shoe I want certain manufacturer should come to top say nike ,if I use bq=brand:nike , That would work fine but if search term changes again nike would come on top , can I write some syntax in  bq where it matches with query as well ?
I know I can handle this with application level , but that would much work to do , I want to do something in request handler itself .

Answer (score 0):

I think this kind of configuration is not supported in Solr, mainly because it depends on a lot of domain-specific factors.

So I guess that your assumption is right, you have to manage that at application level. The only thing that I can tell you is that the custom logic could be implemented in three places:

- client side
- proxy / intermediary
- in Solr